# Issue in showing my UIWebview in IOS 7 properly

Tags: uiwebview, ios7, xcode5

In my app i have a UIWebview in which all the activity is taking place.
The app works perfect on ios6 but with iOS 7 my UIwebview content is colliding with the status bar.

Is there a way i can set the view for my UIWindow to show this properly.

```
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] integerValue] >= 7) {

            if (self.window.rootViewController.view.frame.origin.y <=0) {
                screenBounds = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.window.bounds.size.width, self.window.bounds.size.height-20);
            }
        }
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

Thanks,
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

in the viewDidLoad method of your view controller.